# Survival On Different Planet With Given Resources

Tags: science-based, environment, astronomy, survival, natural-resources

Imagine you are travelling on a space craft “Futura” with a sole aim to find out the EARTH 2.0.

For this, you carry along the following: a dog, a rat, plant seeds (rice), cultures of algae, oxygen cylinders and multivitamin tablets.

In deep space, you realized that fuel of ““Futura” was depleting fast.

You suddenly make a stopover because of depleting fuel at a planet “Carbonica”.

Environment of “Carbonica” is rich in carbon dioxide, both in air as well as in oceans. Design a strategy for the following:

(i) Your own survival

(ii) Your return to Earth

Comment: Is the planet a dead planet? What is your craft fueled by? Since the rice will take time to grow, do we have anything else to eat besides the dog?

Comment: @NexTerren you can make your assumption about the planet. Aircraft is fueled with liquid nitrogen.

Comment: This seems very story-based and potentially broad.  You've essentially reached a point in your plot and are asking us to write the outline of the next chapter.  Our site would be better suited to more specific questions, like "How quickly will algae grow enough to maintain oxygen?"  "Can we use it for food?"  It's also a bit unclear in what you are asking in that we don't know how long you need to stay on the planet, how you obtain fuel, how much fuel you need to get back to Earth, how fast your ship is, how much oxygen you have, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You take the rice and rat first, come back *with the rice*, leqve the rice and take the dog, come back alone, take the rat again.